# Opening TCP Socket to Docker Not Working With Known Configuration Methods

Tags: docker, sockets, tcp, daemon

Attempting to open the TCP socket to my docker daemon so I can use an integration with Home Assistant to interface with Docker and control containers remotely.

I first attempted [this method](https://gist.github.com/styblope/dc55e0ad2a9848f2cc3307d4819d819f) which modifies the `daemon.json` file to add the TCP socket as a host. That didn't work and so I tried to add host arguments to an `override.conf` file in my `docker.service.d` directory as seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/843296/how-do-i-expose-the-docker-api-over-tcp) to a similar result.

In the second case, my journal logs read `dockerd[283854]: "dockerd" accepts no argument(s).`

(I would post the errors for the first method, but this is a live environment so downtime has to be during specific timeframes)

It would seem that in both situations, I cannot get dockerd to accept any host arguments to launch with the TCP socket open. I can only get docker to launch when I don't have these arguments in place. For example, here is my working `daemon.json` file:

```
{
    "log-driver": "journald",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

As a recap:
This doesn't work
(/etc/docker/daemon.json)

```
{
    "log-driver": "journald",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

But this does, without TCP access.

(/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf)

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd daemon
```

I'll do my best to provide more information as requested. But I may need some assistance deriving it upon request.

Thanks for any tips or ideas.

(I would like to mention that I would prefer to open this socket as securely as possible. The host is on a DMZ, so if any other hosts on the VLAN are compromized, this one would also be.)

Comment: Opening an unencrypted TCP socket to the Docker daemon is **incredibly dangerous** – it will allow anyone on your local network to trivially root your host.  Can you change your application to use a safer transport?

Comment: I am aware of the inherent issues with opening TCP to the docker daemon from a security perspective. I unfortunately do not know of any other methods to interface docker with Home Assistant remotely.

Comment: I just found a new tool called MqDockerUp on [Github](https://github.com/MichelFR/MqDockerUp) that may be a solution. I will begin looking into it.